# Redmine db:migrate method not found

Tags: redmine

I am trying to migrate from redmine 1.0 to redmine 2.3 and am getting errors when running db:migrate.

```
sudo rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace

(in /opt/redmine-2.3)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  BuildProjectsTree: migrating ==============================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `inherit_members_changed?' for #<Project:0x7f82e2dad038>
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
/opt/redmine-2.3/app/models/project.rb:85:in `_callback_after_748'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:460:in `_run__1269722363__save__4__callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:104:in `save!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
/opt/redmine-2.3/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:185:in `rebuild!'
/opt/redmine-2.3/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:192:in `call'
/opt/redmine-2.3/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:192:in `rebuild!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `__send__'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
/opt/redmine-2.3/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:189:in `rebuild!'
/opt/redmine-2.3/app/models/project.rb:416:in `rebuild_tree!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/opt/redmine-2.3/app/models/project.rb:414:in `rebuild_tree!'
/opt/redmine-2.3/db/migrate/105_build_projects_tree.rb:3:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `__send__'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

Problem seems to be that project.inherit_members_changed? doesn't exist, but is called on line 85 of project.rb

```
after_save :update_inherited_members, :if => Proc.new {|project| project.inherit_members_changed?}
```

Does anyone know what the source of this problem is?

**::UPDATE::**

I've now tried upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 and get the same error.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
==  BuildProjectsTree: migrating ==============================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `inherit_members_changed?' for #<Project:0x00000004b36d80>
```

Could it be a rake version issue?

I ran bundle install too and installed all the needed gems.

Comment: Which version of Ruby?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ruby is too old. Redmine will deceitfully tell you that the latest version of Redmine works with Ruby 1.8.7, but I lost about two hours to this lie. I have Redmine working on CentOS 6.4 with ruby 1.9.3p385. Try updating to that version and you'll probably be able to run your rake command. Update Ruby thusly:

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ (check out the Third Party Tools/RVM section).

Comment: No love. ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Try doing a gem update

Comment: Upgrading ruby fixed the issue. I did `apt-get purge ruby` and then reinstalled ruby 1.9.3. Migration worked.

Comment: Duh. I've just updated the redmine 1.4.4 to 2.6.1 today, and it's no lie, redmine 2.6.1 runs on ruby 1.8.7-354 as a charm. It autoinstalled rails 3.2.21, maybe this matters. Most new plugins don't work well, so anyway I'm upgrading ruby to 1.9.3 soon.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both solutions above, and the option to edit the database was the only one that worked. Upgrading to Ruby 2.1 did not change anything. However, I can comment that I did not need the 'drop index' commands, and, depending on how many failed migrations I had, I sometimes needed to drop the member roles tables. The final, most repeatable solution I had was to not manually edit the database during the migration but instead I edited the migration files themselves so that the inherit_members field was removed at the right point and added back again at the right point. The two files to edit are:

- `db/migrate/20130202090625_add_projects_inherit_members.rb`

  - Requires addition of the line `remove_column :projects, :inherit_members` before adding the `projects` column
- `db/migrate/105_build_projects_tree.rb`

  - Requires addition of `add_column :projects, :inherit_members, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false` before `Project.rebuid_tree`!

After these two changes, a complete upgrade process can be done in one go without opening a mysql shell (except for the initial create database, user and permissions commands, of course).

Comment: After much fiddling, I ended up using the same solution as you, but moved `add_column :repositories, :is_default, :boolean, :default => false` from `20120115143100_add_repositories_is_default.rb` to `105_build_projects_tree.rb`, below the line you suggested adding.  This, to upgrade from 0.8.4 to 2.5.2-2.  Needless to say, both of our solutions are rather dirty/dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error on Centos 6.2 with Ruby 1.9.3-p392 trying to upgrade to 2.3.0 from 0.8.x. Ruby and gem at latest versions. I did this.

Change the database. You may not have to drop the indexes, I did because of the half upgraded state.

```
alter table projects add column inherit_members boolean default false;
update projects set inherit_members = false;

drop index changesets_repos_scmid;
drop index index_attachments_on_author_id;
drop index index_attachments_on_container_id_and_container_type;
drop index index_attachments_on_created_on;
drop index index_auth_sources_on_id_and_type;
drop index index_boards_on_last_message_id;
drop index index_changesets_on_committed_on;
drop index index_changesets_on_repository_id;
drop index index_changesets_on_user_id;
drop index index_comments_on_author_id;
drop index index_comments_on_commented_id_and_commented_type;
drop index index_custom_fields_on_id_and_type;
drop index index_custom_fields_projects_on_custom_field_id_and_project_id;
drop index index_custom_fields_trackers_on_custom_field_id_and_tracker_id;
drop index index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id;
drop index index_documents_on_category_id;
drop index index_documents_on_created_on;
drop index index_issue_categories_on_assigned_to_id;
drop index index_issue_relations_on_issue_from_id;
drop index index_issue_relations_on_issue_from_id_and_issue_to_id;
drop index index_issue_relations_on_issue_to_id;
drop index index_issues_on_assigned_to_id;
drop index index_issues_on_author_id;
drop index index_issues_on_category_id;
drop index index_issues_on_created_on;
drop index index_issues_on_fixed_version_id;
drop index index_issues_on_priority_id
drop index index_issues_on_priority_id;
drop index index_issues_on_status_id;
drop index index_issues_on_tracker_id;
drop index index_issue_statuses_on_is_closed;
drop index index_issue_statuses_on_is_default;
drop index index_issue_statuses_on_position;
drop index index_journals_on_created_on;
drop index index_journals_on_journalized_id;
drop index index_journals_on_user_id;
drop index index_members_on_project_id;
drop index index_members_on_user_id;
drop index index_members_on_user_id_and_project_id;
drop index index_messages_on_author_id;
drop index index_messages_on_created_on;
drop index index_messages_on_last_reply_id;
drop index index_news_on_author_id;
drop index index_news_on_created_on;
drop index index_queries_on_project_id;
drop index index_queries_on_user_id;
drop index index_repositories_on_project_id;
drop index index_settings_on_name;
drop index index_time_entries_on_activity_id;
drop index index_time_entries_on_created_on;
drop index index_time_entries_on_user_id;
drop index index_tokens_on_user_id;
drop index index_user_preferences_on_user_id;
drop index index_users_on_auth_source_id;
drop index index_users_on_id_and_type;
drop index index_users_on_type;
drop index index_watchers_on_user_id;
drop index index_watchers_on_watchable_id_and_watchable_type;
drop index index_wiki_contents_on_author_id;
drop index index_wiki_content_versions_on_updated_on;
drop index index_wiki_pages_on_parent_id;
drop index index_wiki_pages_on_wiki_id;
drop index index_wiki_redirects_on_wiki_id;
drop index index_workflows_on_new_status_id;
drop index index_workflows_on_old_status_id;
drop index index_workflows_on_role_id;
drop index projects_trackers_unique;
drop index tokens_value;
drop index watchers_user_id_type;

cd /usr/local/redmine
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake tmp:sessions:clear
rake generate_secret_token
rake --trace db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

That one will fail on the column that it originally complained about not existing as in the parent question.
"ERROR:  column "inherit_members" of relation "projects" already exists"

Remove the column and migrate again:

```
alter table projects drop column inherit_members;

cd /usr/local/redmine
rake --trace db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Completes without error.